# Python: check if value is in a list no matter the CaSE

Tags: python, loops

I want to check if a value is in a list, no matter what the case of the letters are, and I need to do it efficiently.

This is what I have:

```
if val in list:
```

But I want it to ignore case

Comment: Note that the `in` operator for lists is iterating all the values internally anyway; if you want efficiency, a `frozenset` is much better

Comment: @Cameron: Depends whether you want O(1) space and O(n) time or vice versa.

Comment: @delnan: How can you get O(1) space?

Comment: @Cameron: Only have `val` and the item to compare to in memory at every given time. Granted, may be impractical.

Comment: @delnan: Oh, I see, I thought you meant for the entire data structure ;-) A `frozenset` is still O(1) memory for searching though

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
check = "asdf"
checkLower = check.lower()

print any(checkLower == val.lower() for val in ["qwert", "AsDf"])

# prints true
```

Using the [any()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any) function. This method is nice because you aren't recreating the list to have lowercase, it is iterating over the list, so once it finds a true value, it stops iterating and returns.

Demo : [http://codepad.org/dH5DSGLP](http://codepad.org/js0PIYxT)

Comment: +1 for being the only one being lazy (that doesn't sounds like a compliment written out... well, you know what I mean). It might also be a good idea to move the `check.lower()` out of the generator expression.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that your values are all of type `str` or `unicode`, you can try this:

```
if val in map(str.lower, list):
...Or:
if val in map(unicode.lower, list):
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really have just a list of the values, the best you can do is something like

```
if val.lower() in [x.lower() for x in list]: ...
```

but it would probably be better to maintain, say, a `set` or `dict` whose keys are lowercase versions of the values in the list; that way you won't need to keep iterating over (potentially) the whole list.

Incidentally, using `list` as a variable name is poor style, because `list` is also the name of one of Python's built-in types. You're liable to find yourself trying to call the `list` builtin function (which turns things into lists) and getting confused because your `list` variable isn't callable. Or, conversely, trying to use your `list` variable somewhere where it happens to be out of scope and getting confused because you can't index into the `list` builtin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and info about list. Although I was just using list to emphasize the example, it is still good to know

Answer (score 0):

You can lower the values and check them:

```
>>> val
'CaSe'
>>> l
['caSe', 'bar']
>>> val in l
False
>>> val.lower() in (i.lower() for i in l)
True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items = ['asdf', 'Asdf', 'asdF', 'asjdflk', 'asjdklflf']
itemset = set(i.lower() for i in items)

val = 'ASDF'
if val.lower() in itemset:  # O(1)
    print('wherever you go, there you are')
```