# Python: Create Login System

Tags: python, authentication

I would like to create a login system using python.

This is a small project that I am doing so that I could get a grip on `python` and eventually send this over to a `webpage` that I am creating.

As of right now I have this:

```
user = raw_input('Create Username: ')
password = raw_input('Create Password: ')
store_user =[roger, Jon]
store_pass =[tennis, soccer]

store_user.append(user)
store_pass.append(password)

if user in store_user:
    print "That user already exsist"

while 1 == 1:
    userguess=""
    passwordguess=""
    key=""
    while (userguess != user) or (passwordguess != password):
        userguess = raw_input('User Name: ')
        passwordguess = raw_input('Password:')

    print "Welcome,",user, ". Type Lock to Lock or Type Create to create another user."
    print store_user
    print store_pass

    while key != "lock":
        key = raw_input("")
```

This gets you to create a user name and password and would store them in a list. 
I threw in that if statement to check the list to see if there the user already exist ( but i don't think that works)

I just want a little bit of guidance on how to get the whole thing to loop: for example you choose if you have a login or not, after you login you have the option to create another, and it would check to see if that user exists already.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You wouldn't normally store passwords, rather something which can be  [generated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Verifying_the_integrity_of_files_or_messages) from a password, and compare that instead.

Comment: Also, see the [`getpass`](http://docs.python.org/library/getpass.html) module, which doesn't echo the password to the screen.

Answer (score 5):

Let us go step by step:

First, the check if the user exists will always tell you it does, because you are adding the user, **then** checking if it exists. So the if statement you wrote is OK, but put it before the `store_user.append`:

```
if user in store_user:
    print "That user already exsist"
else:
    store_user.append(user)
    store_pass.append(password)
```

Second, the condition you wrote for `while 1 == 1:` is useless (but still right), you could do `while 1` (because 1 evaluates to True) or even better `while True:` simply.

Third, the username/password check only checks for the last user and password. If you used `userguess in store_user` and the same for password, you will not get the expected result. So, you need to use dictionaries instead of lists. With these, you can assign a **key** to a **value**. In your case a user to a password, so you will have:

```
store = dict()
# the code to get the user/password
store[user] = password # you "save" the value password for the key user

# then to check:
while not (userguess in store and store[userguess] == passwordguess):
   # try again
```

Read more about dictionaries.

Then, you could store each "logical" procedure in a function to make your code more readable and re-usable. For example:

```
def add_user(store):
    user = raw_input('Create Username: ')
    password = raw_input('Create Password: ')
    if user in store:
        print "That user already exsist"
        return False
    else:
        store[user] = password
        return True

# and call this 10 times for example...
global_store = dict()
for i in range(10):
    add_user(global_store)
```

(Not to mention using classes, etc.)
Do the same for the check password part, and then you can use the loop you made with a bit of changes to do what you expect...

I hope I was clear, and that I helped :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction man!

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the answer your were expecting, but here it goes: DON'T re-invent the wheel.

Use existing tools as much as possible and focus on the functionality you can't get for free.

Comment: I normally would just use php, but I have to do a project for school using python.

Comment: what are some existing tools you'd suggest. Came across this post while looking for what python user systems already existed.

Comment: There are many pyhton frameworks, like web2py (my favorite), django, etc that already handle user management...

Answer (score 2):

this is a good start. I would recommend you checking out: http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/, using data structures like dictionaries will greatly simplify this task.

To see if an item is already in a list, you could iterate through it;

```
for item in list:
    if input == item:
        # item is in list
        break
    # item is not in list
```

A strategy that may also help is to modularize your code into functions. For example, you could have a check_name function that returns True if a user is registered:

```
def check_user(user, user_list):
    for item in list:
        if user == item:
            return True
            break
        return False
```

There are also shorter ways to do this, such as: [Python: check if value is in a list no matter the CaSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371935/python-check-if-value-is-in-a-list-no-matter-the-case)

When you do eventually serve your project online, look into a framework like Django or Flask, they greatly simplify things like logins, managing users, etc. Good luck.

Comment: thanks buddy! Yea I was looking it over again and was like this is could be cleaner, I just got carried away with getting something to work.

Comment: hey mayn, that's all good, we all have to start somewhere and playing with code and finding your own solution is often times the best way to learn.