# How can i sipmlify my code(Python login system)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a new coder. And this is my first login system code with python. How can i simplify my code without losing any functions like wrong username and wrong password etc.?

```
username = "zaphod"
password = "helloworld42"
username2 = "mozzie"
password2 = "mozzietheaussie"
userUsername = input("Hello, What is your username? \n")
UserPassword = input(print("Hello", userUsername, "What is your password? "))
if userUsername == username:
    if password == UserPassword:
        print("Hello", userUsername, "Welcome home")
if userUsername == username:
    if UserPassword != password:
        print("Wrong Password")
if userUsername == username2:
    if UserPassword != password2:
        print("Wrong Password")
if UserPassword == password:
    if userUsername != username:
        print("Wrong Username")
if UserPassword == password2:
    if userUsername != username2:
        print("Wrong Username")
if userUsername == username2:
    if UserPassword == password2:
        print("Hello", userUsername,"Welcome Home")
if userUsername == username:
    if UserPassword == password2:
        print("Are you gonna trick me pal xd")
if userUsername == username2:
    if UserPassword == password:
        print("Are you gonna trick me pal xd")
if userUsername != username:
    if userUsername != username2:
        if UserPassword != password:
            if UserPassword != password2:
                print("Wrong credidentals")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304712/python-create-login-system

Comment: If you have test cases, it will be helpful to answer.

Comment: Even as a new coder, never ever store passwords or compare them as plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the credentials in a `dict` and check if the user name exists and matches the password

```
credentials = {'zaphod': 'helloworld42',
           'mozzie': 'mozzietheaussie'}

user_name = input('Hello, what is your username?\n')
password = input(f'Hello {user_name}, what is your password?\n')

pas = credentials.get(user_name) # returns None if the user name doesn't exists
if not pas:
    print('Wrong Username')
elif pas != password:
    print('Wrong Password')
else:
    print(f'Hello {user_name}, welcome home')
```

The `print("Are you gonna trick me pal xd")` seems to be unnecessary, however you can add it by modifying the `elif`

```
elif pas != password:
    if password in credentials.values():
        print('Are you gonna trick me pal xd')
    else:
        print('Wrong Password')
```